# How to create from a the following json array type a linestring geometry?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I want to create a LineString geometry with sql statements in postgresql :

'LINESTRING(11.617730473115067 48.19782098770711, ..., ..., 11.618709999927699 48.19985004114398)'

from the following JSON Code :

{
"type": [
"LineString",
"LineString"
],
"coordinates": [
[
11.617730473115067,
48.19782098770711
],
[
11.617959999927661,
48.19828004114453
],
[
11.617999999927662,
48.1983600411445
],
[
11.618139999927674,
48.19867004114437
],
[
11.61840999992768,
48.19925004114419
],
[
11.618709999927699,
48.19985004114398
]
]
}

How can i split this JSON Array und concatante to the LineString Text.

Comment: pls show what you have done so far?

Comment: i ask a url, the answer is a big JSON request. From this JSON request i select the part of json above with this statement: json_array_elements(json_array_elements("request" -> 'journeys') -> 'parts') -> 'wayPoints' -> 'coordinates' ->  { "type": [ "LineString", "LineString" ], "coordinates" --> and now i don't know what are the next steps to split the"coordinates"  and concatanate to a geometry expression

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question you can try this :

```
SELECT 'LINESTRING(' || string_agg(e.elt->>0 || ',' || e.elt->>1, ',' ORDER BY e.id) || ')'
  FROM json_array_elements(your_json_code->'coordinates') WITH ORDINALITY AS e(elt, id)
```

This query builds the LINESTRING() with the elements in the order of the json array associated to the key 'coordinates'

Now after reviewing your comments which are not in your initial question, you can try this :

```
SELECT 'LINESTRING(' || string_agg(e.elt->>0 || ',' || e.elt->>1, ',' ORDER BY e.id) || ')'
  FROM routing_import
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_path_query(request :: jsonb, '$.journeys[*].parts[*].wayPoints.coordinates[*]') WITH ORDINALITY AS e(elt, id)
```

Comment: This is My Code until to get the JSON Part --> select
 json_array_elements(json_array_elements("request" -> 'journeys') -> 'parts') -> 'wayPoints' -> 'coordinates' JsonString
from "routing_import";

Comment: Two Problems: first -> string_agg doesn't works, e.elt are integer SQL-Fehler [42883]: FEHLER: Operator doesn't exist: text ->> integer, secound -> 0 and 1 delivery only the first and secound item from the array. The array has mor than 2 items.

Comment: Your first problem : can you please copy paste your code and the error ? `e.elt` is the output of the `jsonb_path_query` function, so it is of type jsonb and not of type text as stated in your comment : "Operator doesn't exist: text ->> integer". The operator `jsonb->>integer` extracts one element from a jsonb array according to its position and convert it in text, `jsonb->>0` is for extracting the first element, `jsonb->>1` is for extracting the second one, etc.

Comment: Your second problem : I have updated my answer adding `[*]` after  `coordinates` in the jsonpath of the `jsonb_path_query` function so that to unnest the first level of the json array associated to the key `'"coordinates"`'. This should solve your second problem.

Comment: first Problem: if i use your code i have the failure SQL-Fehler [42883]: FEHLER: Operator existiert nicht: text ->> integer
  Hinweis: Kein Operator stimmt mit dem angegebenen Namen und den Argumenttypen überein. Sie müssen möglicherweise ausdrückliche Typumwandlungen hinzufügen.
  Position: 61 = Operator doesn't exist, text --> inetger - mybe you should chnage the type of the operator

Comment: SELECT jsonb_path_query(request :: jsonb, '$.journeys[*].parts[*].wayPoints.coordinates[*]')   FROM routing_import; delivery jsonb as type

Comment: now i changed the query in this mode. mybe  there is a better way (but its works): select st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(' || string_agg(e0 || ' ' || e1, ',' ORDER BY foo.id) || ')' , 4326) from (
 select 
 id
 ,e.elt->>0 e0
 ,e.elt->>1 e1
 from routing_import
 cross join lateral
 jsonb_path_query("request",'$.journeys[*].parts[*].wayPoints.coordinates[*]') WITH ORDINALITY AS e(elt, id)) foo;